# Does git use symlinks internally? (FUSE related)

Tags: linux, git, fuse

I'm considering implementing a very basic [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)-based daemon. The problem is that I don't think I will be able to implement symlink support (so then when some app requires this feature to the filesystem I will simply return the errno `ENOSYS` at runtime).

Then the question is about git internals: when you commit and push things to git, are symlinks a fundamental thing that git uses internally inside the .git folder? Will I be able to use git with my FUSE-based mountpoint?

Comment: "are symlinks a fundamental thing that git uses internally inside the .git folder" --- clone some repo and see? Btw, as far as I know git does use symlinks but if target FS/OS doesn't support them - it will just perform worse (and consume more space)

Comment: maybe just cloning a repo is just one case over the many possibilities there could be, depending on the use case?

Comment: git doesn't -- it did, once, but they're not portable to the hinterlands -- but lots of projects do use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, git doesn't use symbolic links internally. However, by default, it does use hardlinks for files under .git/objects while cloning from local repository. You can bypass that with --no-hardlinks.